# Laravel ajax return whole HTML page instead data

Tags: ajax, laravel, routes

I'm having this trouble with the ajax request. This code works on other pages, only on this not working.

I want to call ajax (from different controller - CalendarController) on **"show"** page from controller ClientController - (http://.../client/35) maybe is that wrong

**Client.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#events-list').on('click', '.event-popup', function () { 
        var getEventId = $(this).data('id'); //this line is okay, return dynamic id as i want
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "getEvent/" + getEventId,
            headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
            dataType: 'json',                      
        })
        .done(function (data) {
            console.log(data); //if i remove dataType: 'json' whole page will print in log instead data
        })
        .fail(function(data,jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
            toastr.error("error");
            console.log(data,jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
        })
    });
});
```

Error message from ajax

```
parsererror" SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position
...
responseText: "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="sr"><head>... - WHOLE PAGE
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/getEvent/{id}', 'CalendarController@getEventData');
```

**CalendarController**

```
public function getEventData($id)
{
  $event = Event::findOrFail($id);
  return Response::json($event);
}
```

I added how to Controller looks but does not return data, this ajax call does not come to the controller

I think the problem is somewhere in the URL or because I want to add data with another controller to the **show** page, but I can't figure

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**
Ajax request is redirected for some reason

[image]

Comment: You are most likely returning HTML yet `return Response::json` expects the data to be JSON.

Comment: What are the contents of the html page being returned? Is your ajax request possibly being redirected to the authentication page?

Comment: @RobertRocha I added how to Controller looks but does not return data, this ajax call does not come to the controller, error is before controller

Comment: @JamesClarkDeveloper yea, i didn't look that, error return Homepage not client page where i want to call ajax

Comment: Inspect the network tab to see what the error is.

Comment: @RobertRocha I edited the post with an image from the network tab

Comment: Well clicking on the network tab is a step, now you have to inspect the requests to see which one is failing and see the response.

Comment: If  you forgot to pass the token (csrf), then laravel returns whole page. So check if the token is received in the server.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `findOrFail()` (it returns HTML if the object doesn't exist), use `find()` method. Then you can check if the object exists or not and return json as per the condition.

Example:

```php
public function getEventData($id)
{
  $event = Event::find($id);
  if(!$event) {
     return response()->json([
        'success' => false,
        'message' => 'Not Found'
     ], 404);
  }
  return response()->json($event);
}
```

Comment: As I said, I added how to Controller looks but does not return data, this ajax call does not come to the controller, the error is before controller. 
Ajax is redirected and return error whole Homepage, not client page where I want to call ajax

Comment: have you tried to put a `/` before the URL in `url: "getEvent/" + getEventId,`. Like `url: "/getEvent/" + getEventId,`

Comment: of course, i tried multiple things. I edited the post with an image from network tab

Comment: Add this: `Accept: 'application/json'` on your header request then you will see what actually going wrong. Laravel is redirecting you, may be it's a authentication or validation issue, just check them too

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar kind of problem, in the ajax call simply returns the whole html instead of json data and I resolved the problem by the changing the ajax url. In my case I made the mistake by defining two identical url, one for normal get call with parameter which returns the page and other one is ajax call you can see below:

Route::get('somenameurl/{id}','UserController@userfunction')->name('userfunction');
Route::get('somenameurl/ajaxusercall','UserController@ajaxusercall')->name('ajaxusercall');

I just change the route define for the ajax as below

Route::get('somenameurl/ajaxuser/somecall','UserController@ajaxusercall')->name('ajaxusercall');

and after that ajax call returns the json data.